# De quelle manière diriez-vous « Tu as la face d’un gars qui a bu beaucoup d’alcool la veille au soir »?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation

Tu as la face d’un gars qui a bu beaucoup d’alcool la veille au soir.

Voici d’autres énonciations qui me viennent à l’esprit:

> Tu as la face d’un gars qui s’est grisé jusqu’au petit matin.

> Tu as la face d’un gars qui revient d’une soirée bien arrosée.

> Tu as la face d’un gars qui a abusé de l’alcool la veille au soir.

> Tu as la face d’un gars qui a bu de l’alcool avec excès la veille au soir.

Ou pour faire simple:

> Tu as une face de lendemain de veille

Registre de langue attendu: standard/littéraire.

Comment: On a l'impression que tu as mal aux cheveux.

Comment: En tout case, visage ou tête et pas face. "la veille au soir" n'est pas: hier soir.

Comment: @Lambie Ici, à défaut d'autre référence temporelle, *[la veille au soir](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_a&page=9ajo_Y52Rj7I.html)* ne peut guère être compris que comme une variante de *hier soir*

Comment: @jlliagre Ah bon? Ces phrases dites au présent: "Hier soir, je suis allée au cinema." = La veille au soir, je suis allée au cinéma". La même chose? Vraiment? Je ne pense pas. "la veille au soir = une période antérieure a "hier soir".

Comment: @Lambie *Je suis allée au cinéma* n'est pas au présent.

Comment: *La veille au soir* = le soir qui a précédé le jour de référence.

Comment: @jlliagre Je n'ai jamais dit que Je suis allée au cinéma était **au temps (du verbe) présent. "La veille au soir = le soir qui a précédé le jour de référence.",Exactement: Hier soir je suis allée au cinéma. n'équivaut pas sémantiquement  à "La vieille au soir, je suis allée au cinéma".!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133504/discussion-between-jlliagre-and-lambie).

Comment: " la veille au soir ne peut guère être compris que comme une variante de hier soir"
jlliagre, jamais. Pas pour la phrase donnée dans la question.

Comment: [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/la_veille_au_soir), [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/veille). La _veille au soir_ est hier soir.

Comment: @Ti-culTi-caille Non: la veille au soir \la vɛj o swaʁ\ Le soir de la veille que tu cites de Wiktionnaire. Faut au moins bien citer les choses. La veille au soir n'est absolumment pas hier soir.

Comment: @Lambie Donc il a bu de l'alcool la semaine dernière et son visage en porte les séquelles. Crisse il a bu combien de caribou le gars ?

Comment: @Ti-culTi-caille Le TLFi n'ont plus ne dit que la veille au soir veut dire hier soir. Donc, deux références de ta part qui sont fausses./// Par ailleurs, Il a bu de l'alcool **dimanche soir** et son visage en porte les séquelles. Mais la veille au soir il n'a bu que du café.

Comment: Le débat est intéressant, mais un chat a été créé donc je me permets de "lock" cette question pour éviter de trop diverger. Merci de continuer dans le chat en question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voici ce que je dirais :

> Tu as la tête de quelqu'un qui n'a pas bu que de l'eau la veille...

Remarques:

- ***Face*** n'est plus guère utilisé que dans des expressions plus ou moins figées comme *se voiler la face*, *face contre terre*, *face à face*, *en face de*, *face aux...* Habituellement, on utilise ***visage*** (soutenu) ou simplement ***tête***.
- ***Pas que de l'eau*** est bien sûr un euphémisme pour alcool.
- ***La veille au soir*** signifie *durant la soirée du jour qui précède*, donc, puisqu'on se situe au présent dans la phrase, est équivalent à ***hier soir***. Dans la phrase du titre de la question, il vaut cependant mieux garder ***la veille (au soir)*** plutôt qu'utiliser ***hier (soir)*** car cette dernière expression restreint la signification à une soirée précise alors que ***quelqu'un*** ou ***un gars*** sont génériques et peuvent donc potentiellement avoir cette tête-là n'importe quel jour de l'année.

Answer (score 2):

Je ne dirais pas "face" mais plutôt "tête", je ne préciserais pas qu'il est question d'alcool, c'est évident quand on parle de trop boire.

Je dirais : "Tu as la tête de quelqu'un qui a trop bu hier soir"

Si je devais le reformuler : "Tu donnes l'impression d'avoir un tout petit peu abusé de la boisson", avec certes une pointe de cynisme non demandée.

Comment: Tu as une tête [de] gueule de bois. :) +1 pour cette réponse.

Comment: @Lambie *Tu as une tête gueule de bois* et *tu as une tête de gueule de bois* sont des expressions très étranges qu'heureusement beauchette n'a pas proposées.

Comment: @jlliagre Ce ne sont pas des "expressions".

Comment: @Lambie Mais que sont-ce alors ?

Comment: @Lambie Plutôt *On dirait que tu as la gueule de bois* ?

Comment: @AntonSherwood Bien sûr, mais je ne vois pas de mal à dire avoir une tête de guele de bois. Personne A: Dis donc, t'as vu la tête qu'il a? Personne B: Ouais, une véritable tête de guele de bois.

Comment: @Lambie Ça évoque quelque chose comme une description héraldique pour moi, et je trouve ça presque aussi naturel que _give me a hand hit_ le serait en anglais pour demander un coup de main. Personne de blessé cependant...

Answer (score 1):

> Dure soirée !

Suffit quand exprimé le lendemain matin.

> T'as l'air sur un lendemain de veille.

Usuel pour moi au Québec à l'oral. La référence aux visage serait indirecte avec « t'as les yeux cernés » ou quelque chose du genre.

Comment: "Lendemain de veille" est aussi très usuel en Belgique (je ne me prononce pas pour la France...). Mai on dit plutôt "lendemain de LA veille" ici.

Comment: @Greg Je ne savais pas mais je ne suis plus surpris, c'est une des choses que j'ai apprises ici c'est qu'en Belgique il y a plein de tours qui ressemblent à ceux du Québec mais je ne connais pas assez l'histoire de la Belgique pour comprendre pourquoi. Il doit y avoir eu une coupure d'avec la France qui a permis de conserver des trucs plus anciens je me dis, comme des fossiles. Mon contact avec les Belges remontent surtout à l'âge où je pensais que la Grenadine était l'alcool de prédilection en Europe qu'on servait au goûter et que tous les enfants là-bas avaient des Playmobil ! Donc merci !

Answer (score -1):

> On dirait que tu as passé une bonne soirée hier soir.

ou bien, le métaphorique

> Tu n’as pas l’air d’avoir beaucoup dormi.

Cette seconde formulation est une invitation à expliquer la soirée de la veille.
En revanche, la phrase « tu as la face de… » ne se dit pas (ni ne s’écrit) en français métropolitain, mais peut-être en québécois…